# 3 pole headphone wiring

Tags: wiring, headphones

I'm trying to solder a new headphone plug - 3 pole, i.e. stereo with no mic.
There are 4 wires: copper, red, blue green. I was expecting 3.
Copper and red I understand to commonly be ground and right respectively. Blue and green are confusing me however - what could they be? Blue or green is usually left... but there are both.

They're Etymolic HF5 headphones.

Comment: How about a picture?

Comment: Measure the resistance for each wire with a multimeter: copper-red, and so on as there are 6 combinations. Then draw the schematic and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimentation with Benji007's suggestion of two grounds in mind led me to figuring it out. Turns out it was:

Copper: Left ground

Blue: Left signal

Green: Right ground

Red: Right signal

Answer (score 0):

Copper is most likely a ground and Red is most likely right speaker.  I;m going to guess that Green is Left speaker and Blue is Left ground.

To test this, insert the plug into an audio source.  Play audio.  Hold the wires against the terminals of the plug and listen for sound.

The worst that could happen is you might end up with a speaker having reversed signal and ground, which you probably would never even notice in actual use.

Comment: Out of phase headphones is very noticeable. The result is a big "hole-in-the-middle" stereo image due to the cancellation. The human ear is very sensitive to phase difference and that's responsible, in large part, for sound source location identification.

Comment: Left and right having separate grounds got me on the right track. Obvious in retrospect but was confusing at the time.